# Creating a new column and filling with conditional formatting data

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following code and how do I modify it to add a column (i.e. named style_type) and fill the column with "expensive" if spend is > 2000 or cheap if spend is <2000 for corresponding spend figures.

```
    SELECT ad.site, ad.channel, e.spend
    FROM Extable e INNER JOIN Ads ad ON e.ad_id = ad.ad_id
    WHERE e.spend<=2000 and e.impressions is not NULL;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a `CASE` expression:

```
SELECT ...,
       CASE WHEN e.spend > 2000 THEN 'expensive' ELSE 'cheap' END AS style_type
FROM ...
```

Comment: THis makes sense, but it didn't work. And how do I create a new column to mention print expensive and cheap?

Comment: Oh.. figured! Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT ad.site, ad.channel, e.spend, (CASE WHEN e.spend > 2000 THEN 'expensive' ELSE 'cheap' END) as style_type
FROM Extable e 
    INNER JOIN Ads ad ON e.ad_id = ad.ad_id
WHERE e.spend<=2000 and e.impressions is not NULL;
```

Comment: Yes, figured. Thanks anyway!